# How to check if head is list in F#

Tags: list, f#

Is there a function to check if an object is a list?

I did it like this:

```
try
    let x = unbox<list<obj>>(l)
    ....
with
   | _ -> ...
```

But i would like to check it with an if or match instead if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you know type of list elements you can use such code:

```
let is_list (x: obj) =
  match x with
  | :? list<int> -> printfn "int list"
  | :? list<string> -> printfn "string list"
  | _ -> printfn "unknown object"
```

Comment: I don't know the type, i have list<obj> but I tried it with :? list<obj> and i seams to work :D. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd use:

```
let isList o =
  let ty = o.GetType()
  if (ty = typeof<obj>) then false
  else 
    let baseT = ty.BaseType
    baseT.IsGenericType && baseT.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ list>

if (isList o) then
  ...
```

This will identify lists containing any type of item (int lists, string lists, etc.).